# How to display Dynamic images from GD library to html img tag

Tags: php, html, gd

Hello i have images gotten from the database, after applying image convolution to them i am trying to output the image into an html tag. how do i go around this, have been trying to rack my brain for 3 days now no result looked at all the post i could find still no way to go around this

```
     $eyt = pathinfo($mname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //get image extension
      if($eyt=='jpg' || $eyt=='jpeg' || $eyt=='JPG' || $eyt=='JPEG')         
           {
               $sr=imagecreatefromjpeg('media/'.$mname.'');
           }
            if($eyt=='png' || $eyt=='PNG')
           {
               $sr=imagecreatefrompng('media/'.$mname.'');
           }
            if($eyt=='gif' || $eyt=='GIF')
           {
               $sr=imagecreatefromgif('media/'.$mname.'');
           }

    $matrix = array(
        array(-1, -1, -1),
        array(-1, 16, -1),
        array(-1, -1, -1),
    );

    $divisor = array_sum(array_map('array_sum', $matrix));
    $offset = 0; 
     imageconvolution($sr, $matrix, $divisor, $offset);


        //output what i tried took the output code from a stackoverflow post tried to edit it to my format but no result


      if($eyt=='jpg' || $eyt=='jpeg' || $eyt=='JPG' ||      $eyt=='JPEG')        
           {

        ob_start();
         imagejpeg($sr);
       $raw = ob_get_clean();
        $er= 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode( $raw ) . '';
            }
            if($eyt=='png' || $eyt=='PNG')
           {
               ob_start();
            imagepng($sr);
           $raw = ob_get_clean();
          $er= 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode( $raw ) . '';
           }
            if($eyt=='gif' || $eyt=='GIF')
           {
               ob_start();
            imagegif($sr);
       $raw = ob_get_clean();
      $er= 'data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode( $raw ) . '';
           }

             <img class="img-responsive pad tyi abn"  src="media/<?php   echo  $er ?>" >

    When i check my source code this is what i get
    <img src="media/data:image/jpg;base64," . base64_encode( $raw ) . " >
```

Comment: every instance of `$sr->/* dont know what to insert here /*` just put `$sr` removing the rest

Comment: in addition change `" . base64_encode( $raw ) . "` to `' . base64_encode( $raw ) . '` note the single vs double quotes

Comment: still <img src="media/data:image/jpg;base64," . base64_encode( $raw ) . " > in my source code @cmorrissey

Comment: after the base 64 encode edit i get random long line which i fill is the binary file being called      src="media/data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA+Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2OTApLCBkZWZhdWx0IHF1YWxpdHkK/9s > @cmorrissey

Comment: ah one more edit remove `media/` from `src="media/<?php   echo  $er ?>" >` so it looks like `src="<?php   echo  $er ?>" >`

Comment: it is outputting the image now after i removed the media but it is not applying the sharpen convolution on the image well @cmorrissey

Comment: thats something you will need to adjust to get the look you want, I don't have any experience with that function so I would start with the docs and go from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution @cmorrissey